# adb.exe some ao realizar comando cordova

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Olá, preparei todo o ambiente para trabalhar com o cordova:

1. Instalei Android Studio, Nodejs, Apache Ant, Java;
2. Configurei as variáveis de ambiente e o PATH

Tudo certo. Porém, toda vez que executo o comando:

```
cordova emulate android
```

ou:

```
cordova run android
```

o arquivo `adb.exe` é apagado da pasta `platform-tools`. Quando abro o cmd e digito `adb`, é informado que **não é reconhecido como comando**.

O que poderia estar acontecendo? Lembrando que já fiz todas as instalações via `npm`.